# Android. Is there way to invert order of adding Fragments to LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-linearlayout, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment containing LinearLayout, where programmaticaly added fragments using:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.linear_layout, CheckTemplateFragment.newInstance(*params*).commit();
```

And it filling linear layout from Top to Bottom, but I need it in reverse, Bottom to Top, aka adding new Fragment to first position, on top if linear layout.

I know about .addView(View, index), and with index=0 it will work, BUT it works with Views only, not Fragment.newInstance()
I also tried to change in layout xml:

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

doesn't do trick
I also heared that 'wraping' fragment with View can do trick using .addView instead of .add.
But is there more clean way to do this?

Here xml of fragments that are being added:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/check_template"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context=".CheckTemplateFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_expand"
        android:layout_width="40dp"

        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/button_expand" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_expand" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/check_extra"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_expand"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using fragment cause i need handle button onClick:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                if(isExpanded){
                    extra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn.startAnimation(anim_rot_cw);
                }
                else {
                    extra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn.startAnimation(anim_rot_ccw);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Whatever logic you're using to decide to add fragments-  reverse that, so you add them in the opposite order.  Or don't use Fragments-  they're not a requirement to use, and many companies that write Android apps have style guides that ban them-  they can be problematic for reasons like this over just using views.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm using fragments, cause i have logic on them, i'll update question with code.

Comment: Having logic still doesn't require Fragments.  I would say most companies I've worked for avoid them, they just cause more problems than needed.  They frequently use something very similar to fragments, but home rolled without a lot of the issues of the official class.

Comment: Also, that level of logic is  completely acceptable within a view.  It's business logic you want to keep away from it, not the functionality of the view itself.